# Postgres: Searching all sub-arrays of an array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a Postgres table with a json column, named `raw_data`, that is structured like this:

`[{"id":1234, "name":"John Doe", "purchases":12}, {"id":1234, "name":"Jane Doe", "purchases":11}]`

The number of sub-arrays can differ. It may be 1 or 20 or any number.

I want to perform a query where I can return the entire table row if, say, 'John Doe' occurs in the `raw_data` column. I already know that I can perform a query like this:

`select * from my_table where raw_data->0->> 'name' = 'John Doe'`

But this won't work since the int (zero in this example) is specifying the *nth* sub-array of the array, and I won't know which sub-array to look in ahead of time.

Is there a way to specify a search through *all* sub-arrays?

Comment: Sounds like time to move this data to it's own table. That will be multiple orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Is there a way to perform the search I mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a JSON path expression:

```
select * 
from my_table 
where raw_data @@ '$[*].name == "John Doe"';
```

This assumes that `raw_data` is a `jsonb` column (which it should be). If it's not, you need to cast it `raw_data::jsonb`